# How to show a list in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my situation, how can I show a list into a table? 
In my view i've tried this

```
     @foreach (var AllUsers in Model.AllUsers)
            {
                <td>@AllUsers.Name</td>
                <td>@AllUsers.Email</td>
                <td>@AllUsers.IsActive</td>
            }
```

but I'm getting this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Also here is my controller:

```
 public IActionResult Users()
    {
        using (var aplicationDbContext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();

            var AllUsers = aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id==m.Id);
            user.AllUsers = AllUsers.AllUsers;
            if (AllUsers == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
        return View(AllUsers);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder How did your code compile with above scenario

Comment: @Liam I've already read that thread and tried to fix but still the same error...

Comment: @Manoj what do you mean ?

Comment: the following could be null here `aplicationDbContext`, `aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers`, the result of `aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers.AsNoTracking()` and/or `aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id==m.Id)`

Comment: What is the ModelType of the view? Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: That seems unlikely @DorinMunreanu, because if you'd read and understood that duplicate you would have considerably more null checking in your code.

Comment: If you really have read the linked duplicate, you will have seen that you have to debug your code to find where the actual null reference is.

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id==m.Id);` - that looks wrong.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya "ApplicationUser"

Comment: @stuartd why is that can you explain please ?

Comment: Well, a) it appears you want all users, but you're only selecting one and b) you don't need to check that it's ID is equal to itself.

Comment: `m.Id==m.Id` is **always** going to return `true`...

Comment: You have `Model.AllUsers` is null. Because you are not setting that in the controller. To me it looks like you should have `return View(user);` instead of `return View(AllUsers);`

Comment: your code have `ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();` `user.AllUsers = AllUsers.AllUsers;`.... what's that?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya notice how that `user` variable is scoped ...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya on the line ´AllUsers.AllUsers`... I was testing something just ignore that line

Comment: @rene Scoped variables can be passed as a model to the view. Dorin, if you debug your code properly, `Model.AllUsers` property is null. if you can confirm that it's not then there is some other issue.... Which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: Strange... an "ApplicationUser" class, which logically sounds like it would contain details of _one_ user, then has a property "AllUsers" which contains a list of everyone. It doesn't logically make much sense. Why do you have this confusing object structure?

Comment: @ADyson on my user model I just created a list where every user is saved, isn't that the right way to do this ?

Comment: Not really, no, that's my point. Why would an object called "user" which sounds like it means a single user then contain a list of users? It's illogical and confusing. You can just use a list directly as your model. I'll write an answer which might help you.

Comment: @ADyson please do, if that help's I'll accept it as an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly your object structure doesn't make much sense and can probably be simplified. An "ApplicationUser" class, which logically sounds like it would contain details of one user, then has a property "AllUsers" which contains a list of everyone. It's confusing.

You also have a couple of other logical errors in your code as mentioned in the comments - only returning one row into AllUsers, and returning the wrong object as your model.

So...I think you can do it like this with less fuss:

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Users()
{
    using (var aplicationDbContext = new ApplicationContext())
    {
       var AllUsers = aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers.toList(); //return all users not just the first
       return View(AllUsers);
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model List<ApplicationUser>

<table>
@foreach (var usr in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@usr.Name</td>
    <td>@usr.Email</td>
    <td>@usr.IsActive</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Getting an error on `@Model List<ApplicationUser>`
"The type namespace name "ApplicationUser" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

Comment: Assuming you haven't googled this error yourself yet and solved it, then I'll tell you you need to use the fully qualified namespace of the class to declare it. I don't know which namespace it's in, so it's hard to give you a specific line of code. But something in the pattern `YourApplication.SomeNamespace.SomeSubNamespace.ApplicationUser`. Looking at your code it's probably the namespace where your Entity Framework classes are held. You probably have a `using` statement for that namespace in your controller already.

Comment: I have tried this `@model List<HCCBPOHR.Core.Contracts.Data.ApplicationUser>` but still getting an error"'List<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'AllUsers' and no extension method 'AllUsers' accepting a first argument of type 'List<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I have already fixed the problem, it was my problem, Thanks!